# Do I have to run migrate in django if I don't need admin?

Tags: django

I'm building small website where I will display pages as static pages not from database.

Do I have to run `migrate` when starting a Django project if I don't need to use Django admin interface?

Comment: Why are you using Django at all for this? It is not suited for serving static pages.

Comment: I'm in the learning phase so first i want to build website with django and deploy it as easy as possible. Later i will work on other things.

Comment: you won't be able to access many functionalities like session, authentication, permissions etc. unless you run migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but...

---

Django has three common app which require to run migration at initial stage `auth`, `contenttypes` and `session` which provides all the basic functionalities of authentication, sessions, activity performed etc.

If you are not going to use any of those functionalities then you can run your app without migrations but it will only use your view and templates which is similar to host your html in any simple server without any configuration where you have no need of using such enrich framework like django

Answer (score 1):

To make it short, migrate sets up the database by applying existing migrations in installed apps if it's not set already.

**If your work doesn't use data storage then you can do without running migrate.**

(But this step becomes necessary if you need to store data, and if you just want to serve some static content, you might just consider using a simple HTTP server, like Apache or Nginx).